# Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2. laravel

Tags: laravel, email

i started doing email activation so when a user register to activate their account through an email aadress , so when i create an count i get this errors , i use Mailtrap

```
Address in mailbox given [] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

this is my controller Welcome:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;


    public function ajouter (Request $request) {

        $this->validate($request, [

            'n' => 'required', 
            'mail' => 'required|email',
            'mdp' => 'required',
            'spec' => 'required',
   ]);

        $medecin= new doc() ;
        $medecin->Name=$request->input('name');
        $medecin->Login=$request->input('mail');
        $medecin->Password=$request->input('mdp');
        $medecin->save(); 

        Mail::to($medecin)->send(new Welcome());

        return redirect()->back()->withSuccess('Doctor is here!' ) ; 
    }
```

.env :

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=6721a7b57d1fc4
MAIL_PASSWORD=48b8f83c5caa7d
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose since you have changed the default email field to Login, Mailable can't find it.
You can try with:

```
public function getEmailAttribute()
{
    return $this->Login;
}
```

or

```
Mail::to($medecin->Login)->send(new Welcome());
```